# Mocking Imports within Storybook

Tags: typescript, mocking, storybook

I would like to Mock Imports within my Storybook Stories. I'm following the guide outlined here: [https://storybook.js.org/docs/7.0/react/writing-stories/build-pages-with-storybook#mocking-imports][1]

My decorator and parameters are working as expected but CustomComponent is still importing the production AuthClient instead of the mocked one. I'm guessing that I've configured webpackFinal incorrectly but for the life of me I don't see how.

```
/src/clients/AuthClient.ts
  export class AuthClient()

/__mocks__/AuthClient.js
  export class AuthClient{}

/src/components/CustomComponent.tsx
  import { AuthClient } from 'src/clients/AuthClient';
  private authClient: AuthClient;

/.storybook/main.js
  module.exports = {
    webpackFinal: async (config) => {
      config.resolve.alias['src/clients/AuthClient'] = 
      require.resolve('../__mocks__/AuthClient.js');
    return config;
  }
}
```

Update: The theory right now is that our Stencil components are using rollup and Storybook is using webpack so pathing to the files isn't lining up.
[1]: https://storybook.js.org/docs/7.0/web-components/writing-stories/build-pages-with-storybook#mocking-imports